# Responsive bootstrap menu slight error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a Bootstrap Menu for my website.

On a desktop the website works great, no issues at all.

on a mobile, I have one issue which I cannot seem to solve...

the menu is designed as follows:

```
<body class="background">
    <nav class="content">
        <ul class="exo-menu">
            <li><a class="active" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#" onclick="return false"><i class="fa"></i> Brands</a>
                <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu">
                    <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="A">
                                        <ul class="nav-list list-inline list-inline2">
                                            <li><a data-filter=".89" href="/brand/product"><img src="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/image.png" alt="Image"><span></span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane" id="B">
                                        <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-2">                                
                                            <li><a href="/brand/productb"><span>productb</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">   
                                        <li   class="active change"><a href="#A" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
                                        <li class="change"><a href="#B" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">#B</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#" onclick="return false"><i class="fa"></i> CATEGORIES</a>
            <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu mega-menu2">
                <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-lg-12">
                                        <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-4">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="/product-category/catA">CatA</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-4">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="/product-category/CatB">CatB</a></li>
                                            <li Class= "dropdown-info"><a href="/product-category/CatBa">CatBa</a></li>
                                            <li Class= "dropdown-info"><a href="/product-category/CatBb">CatBb</a></li>
                                            <li Class= "dropdown-info"><a href="/product-category/CatBc">CatBc</a></li>
                                            <li Class= "dropdown-info"><a href="/product-category/CatBd">CatBd</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-4">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="/product-category/CatC">CatC</a></li>
                                            <li Class= "dropdown-info"><a href="/product-category/CatCa">CatCa</a></li>
                                            <li Class= "dropdown-info"><a href="/product-category/CatCb">b</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My problem occurs if I click the category tab after having the brands tab open.
After looking at brands, if i click categories, that tab opens and puts the categories header to the top of the page. which ever sub-category under header gets automatically clicked and loads that page.

I am unsure of any ways to avoid this happening.

the jQueryI have used is:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('.toggle-menu').click(function (){
            $('.exo-menu').toggleClass('display');

            });
        });
</script>
```

Is there a way I can have a slight delay in the menu opening, say .5s but only on mobile devices to hopefully stop this happening?

Any help would be great

Comment: Could you fork and complete this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/eyWear?editors=1111)? What you posted is quite TOO minimal...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Would a link to the site help? I dont have a codepen account and cannot seem to get i looking right on bootsnip.

Comment: The problem appears to be the java/css, in that the brands menu closes very quickly and shoots the categories tab to the top of the screen to open, as a result whichever option my finger is over, in the resulting open drop down, gets selected

Comment: A live link would be usefull... Since it has to be overlooked on mobile. So post the link. ;)